# Flutter - Execute code before setting Home Page

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-getx, homescreen

I have this set up:

```
  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    firebaseUser = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);
    firebaseUser.bindStream(auth.userChanges());
    ever(firebaseUser, _setInitialScreen);
  }

  _setInitialScreen(User? user) async {
    if (user == null) {
      Get.offAll(() => AuthenticationScreen());
    } else {
      if (UserModel.ROLE == "fieldOwner") {
        Get.offAll(() => FieldOwnerHome(user: user));
      } else {
        Get.offAll(() => HomeScreen(user: user));
      }
    }
  }
```

The _setInitialScreen function gets called as soon as a user signs up

I want this code to be executed before that so that the correct Home Screen can be displayed

```
   void signUp() async {
    showLoading();
    try {
      await auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email.text.trim(), password: password.text.trim())
          .then((result) {
        String? _userId = result.user?.uid;

    ///THESE 2 SHOULD FINISH EXECUTION FIRST
        _addUserToFirestore(_userId);
        _initializeUserModel(_userId);

        _clearControllers();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      Get.snackbar("Sign Up Failed", e.toString());
    }
  }


   _addUserToFirestore(String? userId) {
    var role = (authController.isFieldOwnerChecked.value)
        ? "fieldOwner"
        : "user";

    usersCollection.doc(userId).set(
      {
        "name": name.text.trim(),
        "id": userId,
        "email": email.text.trim(),
        "role": role,
      },
    );


  _initializeUserModel(String? userId) async {
    userModel.value = await usersCollection
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(doc));
  }
```

What is happening is the Get.offAll() in the _setInitialScreen gets called first; thus the wrong Home Screen gets called.

Comment: don't know if it helps but i noticed `_initializeUserModel` is async, so maybe await for it? like `await _initializeUserModel(_userId);`

Comment: No that doesn't help because the first thing that gets called is the _setInitialScreen function.

Comment: If you want those 2 functions to act as a synchronous operation, assing them Future at the beggining: `Future<void> _addUserToFirestore(String? userId)` and `Future<void> _initializeUserModel(String? userId)` , then await those 2 functions in `signUp()`.  Future helps you to add those functions in front of the event loop, so they will be executed before anything, remember you have to put them before the operations you want them to be behind.

Comment: Not exactly, what I want is that the _setInitialScreen function doesn't get called as soon as the user signs up. It is the first thing that gets called; which is what I need to avoid.